# How to get topologically sorted list of Gradle sub-projects?

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a tool that needs a topological sort of the sub-projects in a multi-module project. Does Gradle have a way to provide this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for my purposes.

```
class ProjectCategory {
    static List<Project> topologicallySortedProjectDependencies(Project project) {
        topologicallySortedProjectDependenciesImpl(project).unique().reverse()
    }

    private static List<Project> topologicallySortedProjectDependenciesImpl(Project project) {
        final dependencies = project.configurations.compile.dependencies.findAll { dependency ->
            dependency instanceof ProjectDependency
        } collect { ProjectDependency projectDependency ->
            topologicallySortedProjectDependenciesImpl(projectDependency.dependencyProject)
        } flatten()

        dependencies + project
    }
}

task topologicallySortedProjects << {
    println project(':').toString().capitalize()

    use(ProjectCategory) {
        project.topologicallySortedProjectDependencies().each { projectDependency ->
            println "+--- ${projectDependency.toString().capitalize()}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define topological sort. You can get the list of subprojects in your rootProject's build.gradle file by referencing the `subprojects`. Like this:

```
subprojects.each { p ->
  println p.path
}
```

You can sort these by their path (which is the fully qualified name (ie. `:module:submodule`)

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
final class ProjectManager {

    private static printSubProjects(Project project) {
        project.subprojects.each { p ->
            println p.path
        }
    }
}

rootProject {

    task listAllProjects << {
        println project(':').toString()
        ProjectManager.printSubProjects(project)
    }
}
```

> cd root_gradle_project
>
> gradle listAllProjects

Comment: This looks like it'll just list the projects rather than listing them topologically sorted.